# È corretto 'la ministra' o 'la Presidenta' o la 'Presidentessa'?

Tags: word-choice, gender

In un tweet della Camera dei deputati si legge,

> Domani alle 14 *la ministra* degli Esteri @FedericaMog riferirà alle Commissioni Esteri riunite sugli sviluppi della situazione in #Ucraina

Ritenete sia corretto usare il femminile *la ministra*? To me, it sounds strange.

E se mai avessimo un Presidente donna, dovremmo poi dire *la Presidenta* o *la Presidentessa*? E se no, quando queste parole devono essere declinate al femminile?

Comment: “se mai avessimo un Presidente donna”: di presidenti donna ce ne sono già numerose, per fortuna, anche in Italia, per esempio in enti e associazioni, e anche (e dai tempi di Nilde Iotti) in una delle camere del parlamento.

Comment: Sì, e ricordo anche Irene Pivetti, quale ulteriore importante esempio insieme a Nilde Iotti.

Comment: Qualunque sia la risposta "corretta", parliamo di aspetti della lingua in rapida evoluzione, a causa dell'altrettanto rapida evoluzione della società. Colgo l'occasione per lanciare _dottrice_ al posto di _dottoressa_ :-) ... e visto che ci sono, faccio il tifo anche per _avvocata_

Comment: ... sì, lo so, _dottrice_ non avrà molto successo, ma ad _avvocata_ ci tengo

Comment: @Walter, esilarante, yes; in un mondo che tende alla parità di genere appare ridicolo aggiungere o creare distinzioni fra la forma neutra, cioè il maschile, e quella femminile.

Answer (score 12):

Attenzione: “ministro” e “presidente” sono due casi molto diversi. Il primo è un normale sostantivo maschile, eventualmente passibile di femminile in “-a”; il secondo è etimologicamente un participio presente, e quindi è invariante al femminile.

Comment: mah. Il participio di presiedere è presiedente, ho appena controllato sul De Mauro :-)

Comment: @mau: Io scrivo le cose a ragion veduta. :-) Non ho detto che sia attualmente il participio di un verbo odierno, ho detto che lo è etimologicamente: “dal lat. *praesĭdens -entis*, part. pres. di *praesidere* «presiedere»” (Treccani, ovviamente).

Comment: Però la cosa che mi è sembrata strana è che la Treccani dice "s. m." e poi precisa "f. invar." mentre per esempio in [dirigente](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dirigente/) dice "agg. e s. m. e f.". Non sono sicuro che la differenza di trattamento sia giustificata, forse sarebbe stato più corretto dire direttamente "s. m. e f.".

Comment: Presidentessa è sempre sbagliato? Mi pare che sia un termine ricorrente, principalmente in film americani o in fumetti giapponesi. (la presidentessa del club di XYZ)

Comment: @Leggy7: Il concetto di “sbagliato” sulle questioni linguistiche va sempre preso con cautela ma, sì, eviterei di usare “presidentessa”. Noterai che le fonti che citi sono *traduzioni*, e per giunta svolte spesso in tempi ristretti (legati all'uscita del film o fumetto), con molti vincoli concreti (il movimento delle labbra, le dimensioni del balloon) e qualche volta svolte da persone molto immerse nella cultura di partenza e a cui può sfuggire qualche imprecisione.

Comment: Aggiungerei per chi usa “presidentessa” che, se fosse una formazione regolare e accettabile, dovremmo dire anche “dirigentessa”, “componentessa”, “insegnantessa”...

Comment: @DaG: what about *studens*, *-entis*? :-)

Answer (score 9):

Secondo l'[Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/comunicato-stampa/crusca-risponde-ministro-ministra) si deve dire «la ministra», «la presidente».

Nota che «[ministra](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ministra/)» in lingua italiana esiste da sempre; «[presidentessa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/presidente/)» è usato quasi solo con tono scherzoso. Secondo la Treccani «presidente» è maschile e si applica anche per il femminile (ma DaG l'ha spiegato meglio: è originariamente un participio presente, quindi è invariante, sia maschile che femminile).

Comment: "La Presidentessa" era il titolo di uno dei film salaci di Luciano Salce, a conferma dell'uso scherzoso del termine.

Answer (score 3):

Le regole dell'italiano sono abbastanza chiare, anche se l'uso le ha rese nebulose. Qui si tratta di rimuovere inspiegabili eccezioni, tra l'altro abbastanza recenti, visto che i ruoli di sindaco e ministro non sono aperti alle donne da molto - non dimentichiamo che è solo dal dopoguerra che le donne possono votare. Le regole generali (nota però che ci sono sempre eccezioni):

- generalmente i nomi di professioni rispecchiano il genere
- se  la parola al maschile finisce con O, la versione al femminile finisce con A. Sempre. Non si capisce bene perché monaco / monaca, cuoco / cuoca, ma non sindaco / sindaca. È una presa di posizione anti-femminista, tutto qua. La Sindaca, la Ministra, vanno benissimo
- se la parola finisce con la E

  - in alcuni casi si usa 'essa' per il femminile; bisogna controllare sul dizionario se questa variazione esiste. Per esempio dottoressa, campionessa
  - se finisce con 'tore', il femminile è 'trice' - direttrice, ispettrice, ma con eccezioni (questore / questora, revisore / revisora)
  - in tutti gli altri casi la parola è la stessa per entrambe le persone, la supplente, la presidente, la cancelliere, ma cambia l'articolo
- se la parola finisce con la A al maschile, resta invariata al femminile singolare: la guardia, l'autista, l'atleta, ma poi cambiano le regole per il plurale (le guardie, gli atleti / le atlete)

**EDIT** aggiunto questora, revisora come suggerito da @DaG

Comment: Grazie per l'articolata risposta, ma potresti usare gli accenti corretti (“è”, non “é”), visto anche che questo è un sito dedicato alla lingua italiana? Per rimanere nel merito della questione, cito questo recente [post di Vera Gheno](https://www.facebook.com/wanderinglinguist/posts/10155060203345915), linguista della Crusca, sostanzialmente in accordo con questa risposta.

Comment: Visto che non sei in grado di cogliere le differenze nell'ortoepia italiana, scegli di sbagliare? Liberissimo, ma forse un sito in cui si viene per imparare o migliorare l'italiano non è la tribuna migliore per le tue idiosncrasie. E comunque complimenti per il garbo da lord inglese.

Comment: E tornando nel merito della faccenda, sei sicuro delle “regole” sulle parole che finiscono in “-e”? “Questrice” mi sembra poco usato, a favore invece di “questora” (fra chi adotta una forma femminile). E in ambito editoriale è usuale dire “revisora” come femminile di “revisore”. Potresti approfondire di più?

Comment: O forse le differenze sono così minuscole che mantenere due tipi di accenti per indicarle è solo un manierismo senza alcuno scopo pratico. Le lingue si evolvono, dopotutto. Questo é un sito dove si risponde a domande. In quanto ai tuoi due esempi sulla finale -e hai ragione, edito la mia risposta.