# "la sindaco".. - nuova tendenza o semplicemente un typo?

Tags: word-usage, grammar

Essendo di madrelingua italiana e vivendo in Germania, non mi scandalizza affatto la, tanto discussa, femminizzazione dei titoli, delle cariche e dei nomi di professione e simili a seconda del contesto (verso una lingua, quasi, asessuata oserei dire - opinione personale questa scaturita dal parallelo con [Die Feministische Linguistik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feministische_Linguistik) che incontrai a lezione, qualche anno fa, di tedesco qui in Germania).

Leggendo qualche articolo sul sito dell [Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/comunicato-stampa/crusca-risponde-ministro-ministra) ([e oltre](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/tema-del-mese/infermiera-s-ingegnera)), una interminabile discussione su wikipedia anche, [Panico linguistico su nomi di cariche e professioni di genere femminile](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bar/Discussioni/Secondo_l%27Accademia_della_Crusca_bisogna_dire_%22Sindaca%22), e poi anche in [italian.stackexchange](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1735/%C3%88-corretto-la-ministra-o-la-presidenta-o-la-presidentessa), e sul sito della [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_547.html), mi ero abituato a usare "la sindaca" ed altri ancora, ma nemmeno il tempo di farci l'abitudine che mi ritrovo a leggere "***la sindaco***" da una pagina de "[Il Fatto Quotidiano](http://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2017/04/24/elezioni-francia-per-favore-macron-non-e-il-renzi-francese/3540246/)", ovvero:

> Come propone ***la sindaco*** di Barcellona Ada Colau, indicendo dal 9 all’11 giugno un incontro nella sua città, con la partecipazione degli aderenti al movimento Fearless Cities, città senza paura.

[image]

Personalmente metterei in dubbio che si intenda "***la sindaco***" in senso ironico se non addirittura dispregiativo ([Ada Colau](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Colau) non è una donnetta); tanto meno riesco a pensare che sia un refuso/typo/lapsus durante una qualche misteriosa digitazione (anche se lo spero).

Ad ogni modo, è possibile scrivere "***la sindaco***"? Qualora no, perché? Può sembrare banale come domanda, e se tale risulta chiedo venia, tuttavia dinanzi a questi nuovi termini femminili ancora oggi trovo non tanto immediato, in certi casi, una regola schietta che mi permetta di rispondere alla domanda suddetta aldilà di un approccio da madrelingua e d'uso quotidiano. Per me la grande questione era se usare il maschile "ovunque" o ammettere termini femminili per le donne scritti secondo le regole, e l uso era tra "*il sindaco*" e il naturale "*la sindaca*" (e non "**la sindaco**"), ma non vorrei che quelli del Fatto Quotidiano scrivano correttamente e magari inaugurano un nuovo uso del termine...

Comment: Non sono al passo con le più recenti tendenze, ma trovo che eliminare il genere grammaticale dalla lingua sia orribile. O diciamo *il sindaco* o *la sindaca/sindachessa*. Personalmente preferisco il primo, ma ad ogni modo *la sindaco* è semplicemente inguardabile.

Comment: @Denis Nardin, ma non si elimina tanto il genere penso, tanto meno si vuole fare prevalere l uno nei confronti dell altro. L uso suona piú come "perché no? Gli articoli ci sono e le parole suonano"... poi, non sono un esperto di lingua tanto meno un linguista, ma sono aperto a tutte le adeguatezze e variazioni!

Comment: Tuttavia, proprio la diffusione di questi termini parte dall uso che ne facevano i giornali e i media... se sbaglio corrreggetemi, ma l Accademia dice che si accetta l uso di `"la sindaca" come una sorta di femminile per "il sindaco", allora mi domando "perché no "la sindaco"?" O meglio, perché lo scrivono (i giornali come il Fatto)? A prima lettura prima dell pubblicazione salta all occhio e in questi tempi, data la tematica/questione, fa pensare!

Comment: “La sindaco” non ha nessun senso, né linguistico né “logico” (per il poco che c'entra la logica nelle questioni di lingua). Poi, se uno vuole uno è libero di dirlo e scriverlo, ma è esattamente come scrivere “la professore” o “la segretario”. Di un argomento affine si è parlato qui, oltre che nella domanda che citi, anche [in questa](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2388/uno-dei-pi%C3%B9-grandi-fisici-o-una-delle-pi%C3%B9-grandi-fisiche-detto-di-una-donna).

Comment: @mle: Che intendi con «"la sindaca" come una sorta di femminile per "il sindaco"»? Perché “una sorta”? Qual è un esempio di femminile che non è “una sorta”?

Comment: @mle La desinenza in *-o* tipicamente indica un genere grammaticale maschile (che non vuole dire che il soggetto sia di sesso maschile in alcun senso biologico, per esempio *il notaio* può benissimo essere una donna). Non è una regola fissa, ma rompere le regole per il solo gusto di farlo non ha senso. Inoltre *la sindaco* non suona per niente a me...

Comment: @DaG, quel "sorta" non é dell Accademia detto/scritto, é piú un mio modo discorsivo di affermare (Pardon!), del tipo "non é una sorta di femminile? Se si, dato il comunicato anche dell accademia, perché anche "la sindaco" é usato come oggi ho letto? E se l uso é errato, aldilá del comunicato della Crusca che non si esprime su "la sindaco" come femminile di "il sindaco" (se correttamente ho letto tutti i link trovati), perché?"... Spero di essermi fatto capire!

Comment: Non ho capito bene il tuo ragionamento, @mle, ma non c'è dubbio che “la sindaca” sia il femminile di “il sindaco”, senza “sorta” o altro, così come “la segretaria” lo è di “il segretario” e così via. Che cos'è, se non è il femminile? Premesso che secondo me quello che scrive il FQ è o un errore o una mezza spiritosaggine, se mai dovesse entrare nell'uso potrebbe ipoteticamente diventare un altro femminile. Scriveresti che “i corni” è una sorta di plurale di “il corno” perché esiste anche la forma “le corna”?

Comment: (Ti imploro, @mle, usa ogni tanto qualche apostrofo e qualche accento grave. Mi sanguinano gli occhi, a leggerti... :-) )

Comment: @DaG, ti ringrazio per le correzzioni al post, in tedesco l´apostrofo é quasi inesistente se non per certe abbreviazioni, ed io non ci faccio caso, quando scrivo in italiano, ad inserirlo, metti pure che ho la tastiera tedesca e capirai, cercherò tuttavia di fare più attenzione.

Comment: @DaG, capisco quanto hai scritto, e non per polemizzare o mettere altra carne a fuoco, piú per capire un attimino, mi viene da dirti: "solo perché l´accademia della Crusca non si é espressa su "la sindaco", sancendo "la sindaca" come femminile di "il sindaco", permette un ulteriore ipotetico femminile, quale sarebbe eventualmente "la sindaco"? Spiritosaggine, errore o meno, il mio pensiero era questo, il FQ risulta essere giustificato ad usare quel "la sindaco", visto che "errore rosso" quasi non sembra se mai dovesse entrare nell'uso?!"

Comment: @Dag, oh.. ho visto ora i links che hai linkato!

Comment: @mle: È sempre difficile dire in termini assoluti che cosa sia “corretto” o “sbagliato” nelle lingue umane. Quasi ogni parola o regola grammaticale era inizialmente un “errore” (o, detto in modo più neutro, un'innovazione), che poi si è diffuso al punto di diventare parte della lingua. Tutto l'italiano, ipersemplificando, è un latino pieno zeppo di errori. Quindi se fra dieci anni tutti diranno “la sindaco”, sarà considerato “corretto”; se questa forma sarà dimenticata, era un “errore” che è morto lì. (E ovviamente ci sono varie  possibili vie di mezzo: usi diversi che convivono tra loto.)

Comment: @DenisNardin, "la notaia" esiste, e per me suona e si accosta bene, e da nessuna parte ancora ho trovato scritto "la notaio", chissá un giorno!

Comment: @DaG, quoto in toto, studiando tedesco notai di come furono introdotti dei veri e propri suffissi alle parole maschili con regole di composizione per avere i rispettivi femminili, e tutto, tranne per certi casi (come ovvio sembra che ci siano eccezioni ma poche), sembra maturamente composto linguisticamente, ecco, questa cosa mi é difficile pensare di averla ad oggi nell´italiano, sará l´italiano forse ancora una lingua giovine e poco matura e come dici tu?!

Comment: @DaG, io sono, saró di parte, per la correzione in "la sindaco" o in "il sindaco" o in "in ruolo di sindaco.."... spero si accorgono! In parte sono stanco dei hashtag sui social e delle battaglie che si fanno sul web per conservare questo o altro o per proporre neologismi! (opinione personale). Grazie per gli spunti e le opinioni che hai dato... ;)

Comment: Mi sembra che il modo in cui "evolvono" il tedesco e l'italiano sia completamente agli antipodi. In Germania, per esempio, sono riusciti addirittura a cambiare l'ortografia dall'alto, d'autorità; in italiano invece non c'è nessun tipo di guida o controllo sull'evoluzione della lingua. Questo ovviamente suggerisce paragoni con la cultura dei due popoli...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le forme più comuni sono la sindaca... o il sindaco... seguito dal nome femminile. La sindaco sembra un'espressione  eccentrica ma non di uso comune. Personalmente la eviterei.

[La sindaca è donna, non una donna sindaco](http://www.repubblica.it/cultura/2016/11/18/news/sindaco_sindaca_crusca_italiano-152283266/):

> - Fra tutti i dubbi, questo è quello che meno ci tormenta. ***Complice la recente elezione di Raggi e Appendino***, a Roma e Torino, possiamo affermare che il sostantivo che qualifica il primo cittadino (la prima cittadina, anzi!) ***abbiamo finalmente imparato a usarlo come si deve: facile facile, con la a, al posto della o; al femminile, cioè, se riferito a una donna.***  Vale lo stesso per l'utilizzo di ministra, sdoganato a tutti gli effetti. E a chi cerca le vie di mezzo e insiste a definire Boschi la ministro, ecco l'esempio a cui guardare: direste mai la maestro, pur avendo la versione femminile di quella parola, lì, a portata di mano?

(www.repubblica.it)

[Come si dice correttamente sindaco al femminile? È corretto chiamare "sindaco" anche una donna?](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_547.html)

> - Non siamo di fronte a una questione di correttezza grammaticale, ma di adeguatezza nel trattare i nomi di mestiere al femminile.
>     ***Chi scrive il sindaco Anna Rossi non sbaglia**, semplicemente preferisce usare il nome di mestiere sindaco trattandolo come se fosse una sorta di “neutro”, inclusivo dei riferimenti di genere maschile e femminile, che si riferisce a una categoria professionale in termini di funzione generale.
>     ***Chi scrive sindaca adopera con efficacia le risorse flessive messe tranquillamente a disposizione dalla nostra lingua: sindaco/sindaca, avvocato/avvocata, postino/postina, ecc. seguono la normale alternanza nominale di genere maschile/femminile, espressa attraverso le uscite -o e -a.***

(www.treccani.it)

Ci sono alcuni altri esempi dell'uso "la sindaco" come:

Da [Dalle pratiche di partecipazione all’e-democracy: Analisi di casi concreti ...](https://books.google.it/books?id=P4u9BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA265&dq=la%20sindaco&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjch4u69r3TAhVBWBoKHU4zAZYQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=la%20sindaco&f=false)

> - Cinque anni dopo la sconfitta del 1999, per vincere le nuove elezioni ***contro la sindaco uscente, Giustina Destro***, su consiglio del suo regista per la campagna elettorale, Marco Marturano, che cinque anni prima aveva portato alla vittoria la candidata Destro.

Da 
[Educazione democratica per una pace giusta](https://books.google.it/books?id=ev9cqhwaNW8C&pg=PA37&dq=la%20sindaco&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjch4u69r3TAhVBWBoKHU4zAZYQ6AEIQTAH#v=onepage&q=la%20sindaco&f=false):

> - ***La sindaco di Napoli***  trovava significativo che tutte le personalità studiate nel mio volume avessero « condiviso, seppure in tempi e contesti profondamente diversi

Comment: non sapevo che era dapprima giá in uso.. grazie per le fonti!

Comment: @mle - in realtà sono solo alcuni tra i rari esempi che sono riuscito a trovare con Google.  Non penso che stia  diventando di uso comune.

Comment: Attenzione, @mle, “in uso” significherebbe che è una locuzione largamente diffusa, non che cercando bene se ne trovano due esempi (che potrebbero benissimo essere errori: cercando, si trova anche [“la tavolo”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22la+tavolo%22&oq=%22la+tavolo%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2905j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22la+tavolo%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks)...).